# What generates the ICE candidates on a local webRTC application with no STUN server specified?

Tags: webrtc, stun

I wish to understand what generates the ICE candidates in a local webRTC application that does not use a STUN server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a STUN server configured, the only candidates you might get from `onicecandidate` are *host* candidates, based on your system's IP address in its local network. The browser running on your system already knows this IP, and does not need ask a STUN server for it.

A STUN server is only needed to learn what IP addresses a system might be contactable on from outside a NAT. A STUN server acts as a mirror that sends back the IP it sees from packets sent through the NAT.